# How to download image object on page as a file in html?

Tags: html, dom

I am creating an image dynamically on the page using dataURL,

```
    var aImg = document.createElement('img');
    aImg.setAttribute('src', dataURL);
    aImg.setAttribute('alt', 'pic');
    aImg.setAttribute('width', '438px');
    aImg.setAttribute('height', '267px');
    aImg.onclick = (function() {
         //download the image object
    })();
```

I am not sure what to do to download this image object that is a PNG image.
Can someone give hints?

Comment: What is your specific question?  A data URL already contains the data so there is no need to download anything from a server.  If you want the image to be visible, you would need to insert it into your page.  Also, there's no reason to use `.setAttribute()` here.  You can just refer to the properties directly such as `aImg.src = dataURL;`

Comment: Do you mean "download" as the browser display the image, or "download", have the datURL converted to a regular file and saved to the user's hard drive?

Comment: @DanGoodspeed yes exactly I want the user to have the image as an image file on their disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the image to be displayed the follwing should be fine :

```
aImg.src = YOUR_URL
```

if you want to save it on to the file , you shoud redirect and let the browser take care of the rest. JS redirect can be done as follows :

```
window.location.replace(dataURL)
```

If you want the browser to give a pop-up saying "Save File" check out this link : http://muaz-khan.blogspot.in/2012/10/save-files-on-disk-using-javascript-or.html